# Relacionar Tabla de cuenta y Tabla de transacciones en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Quiero relacionar 2 tablas una de cuentas y la otra de Transaciones, para después mostrar cuales son las transacciones de una cuenta en específica no de todas las cuentas.
Entonces tengo varias cuentas y en cada una hago transacciones cómo puedo hacer que la transacción se agregue a la cuenta que quiero para luego monstrar todas las transacciones de esta cuenta.

Esta es la forma en la que creo la cuenta y la guardo en la base de datos

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cuentas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('Nombre');
            $table->string('Descripcion');
            $table->integer('Interes');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

y quiero crear otra tabla que se relacione con el id de esta como podría hacerlo.

Cree la migración y el modelo `Transaccion` para poder relacionarlas y las usé así:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('transaccions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('Cantidad');
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->integer('cuenta_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('cuenta_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('cuentas');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

y me da el error de :

```
 General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `transaccions` add constraint `transaccions_cuenta_id_foreign` foreign key (`cuenta_id`) references `cuentas` (`id`))
```

Comment: Por agrega la estructura de la otra tabla

Comment: Puedes crear tu migración de transacciones agregando como un campo un integer llamado 'cuenta_id', posteriormente deberas crear una relación en sus respectivos modelos.

Comment: cree la migracion  y modelo y le coloco a la tabla:
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('transaccions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('Cantidad');
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->integer('cuenta_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('cuenta_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('cuentas');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: y me da este error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `transaccions` add constraint `transaccions_cuenta_id_foreign` foreign key (`cuenta_id`) references `cuentas` (`id`))

Comment: Por favor no pongas el código de lo que has tratado en los comentarios pues se hace difícil seguir lo que llevas, edita tu pregunta y coloca lo necesario

Comment: Ya vi tu error, en la tabla cuentas tu clave primaria es `bigIncrements` pero en la tabla `transaccionts` tu clave fornaea solo es `integer`, entonces la solución es que la columna `cuenta_id` la declares como **bigInteger** @WilmerFabianBermudez

Comment: gracias ese era el error no sabia que pudiera dar error ello.